# OpenLayers as a large (changing and growing) image viewer

Tags: javascript, image, openlayers

Basically, what I'm trying to do is use a map viewer as an image viewer with the same sort of efficient tile-loading, zoom/pan awesomeness without having to build it myself.

Specifically, I need an image viewer that will allow the image to grow and change while not altering the coordinates of any older (unchanged) tiles. This means that the center point (0,0), where the image started growing from, must always remain (0,0). So I'm looking for a library that will allow me to use a very basic Cartesian coordinate system (no map projection!), which will ask for tiles infinitely in all directions with no repetition (as opposed to how map libraries just ignore y-axis above and below the map, but the x axis repeats).

There's another catch. I need zoom level 0 to be zoomed *in* all the way. Since the image is constantly growing, there's no way to tell what the max zoom level will be, and the coordinates need to be based on the base image layer tiles so that every tile in zoom level z contains 2^z base layer tiles.

I am wondering if this is possible with OpenLayers and how to do it. If it's not, any suggestions of other (open-source javascript) libraries that can do this would be very appreciated! I've tried playing around with [Polymaps](http://polymaps.org/), but the documentation is lacking too much for me to be able to tell if it will work. So far no luck.

Please let me know if none of this made sense, and I'll try to include some images or better explanations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Polymaps after all, since I like it more than OpenLayers, because it's faster and has much smoother scrolling and panning. I wasn't able to do exactly what I wanted, but what I did was close enough.

I ended up writing my own layer (based on the po.image() layer), which disabled infinite horizontal looping of the map. I then wrote my own version of po.url() that modified the requests going to the server for tiles so that zooming was reversed (I just arbitrarily picked a 'max' zoom of 20, then when making a request subtract the zoom level from 20) and the x and y coordinates were converted to cartesian coordinates from the standard row, column coordinates Polymaps uses, based on the zoom level and the map centered at (0,0).

If anyone is interested in the code I can post it here. Let me know!

EDIT: I've posted the code on github at https://github.com/camupod/polymaps

The relevant files are src/Backwards* and examples/backwards (though it actually doesn't work, you might be able to clean some information about how it *should* work).

Comment: @dm03514 I posted my code on github. Sorry about the lack of documentation, but I don't have time to go through and get everything working again.